# If an array is not full add a value to the end

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So i'm working on some code that is suppose to check if all my array slots are full and if there not add my new grade to the next slot in the array and return true and if it is full return false.

I'm confused on how to check if my array(grades) is full or not.. I have something like this but not quite sure if its correct.

The probelm is for some reason it seems to be only adding one grade. This is also effecting my score which is producing ? as a number which is something i have never seen before.

```
public boolean addGrade(int newGrade) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        if (grades[i] == -1)//or should i use 0 {
            grades[i] = newGrade;
            numGrades++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

score method (all its suppose to do is compute and return the score: score total / totalGrades)

```
public double computeScore() {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        total += grades[i];
    }
    return total / totalGrades;
}
```

Comment: As you are doing total hence use `0` as default value instead of `-1`

Comment: What type is `grades`?

Comment: int []grades and was hoping to leave it as that and not Interger

Answer (score 1):

since you are maintaining a counter variable `numGrades` hence use it directly to insert a new item at desired location.

```
public boolean addGrade(int newGrade) {
    if(newGrades<grades.length){
        grades[numGrades] = newGrade;
        numGrades++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Note:** *Each value in an array is by default zero.*

Comment: Shouldn't `if(newGrade<grades.length){` be testing `numGrades`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch obviously that is by mistake added.

Answer (score 1):

You could even tighten up a tad by incrementing inside of the array brackets:

```
public boolean addGrade(int newGrade) {

      if (numGrades < grades.length) {
        grades[numGrades++] = newGrade;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You shouldn't do what you're doing. You have `numGrades`, I think you are should use it to track the correct position in `addGrade()`!

```
if (numGrades < grades.length) {
  grades[numGrades] = newGrade;
  numGrades++;
  return true;
}
return false;
```

Also then

```
public double computeScore() {
  double total = 0;
  if (numGrades == 0) {
    return total;
  }
  if (numGrades > grades.length) {
    numGrades = grades.length;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < numGrades; i++) {
    total += grades[i];
  }
  return total / numGrades;
}
```

Comment: for some reason my score has been producing "?" which is really weird to me

Comment: @dave Edited. Presumably `totalGrades` is 0. And, I don't think you need it. Either `totalGrades` or `numGrades` - not both.